# Eliminar correos repetidos dentro de un Array

Tags: javascript

Actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo javascript y ahora estoy en la parte de Array Unique, he realizado varios ejercicios quitando valores repetidos dentro de un Array. Todo bien, pero mi duda surge al tratar de quitar direcciones de correos repetidos dentro el mismo array. ¿Como puedo eliminar los correos repetidos y separarlos por dominio?

```
var correos = ['al221511338@gmail.com'
,'rodrigo@gmail.com'
,'al221511338@gmail.com'
,'detox@live.com'
,'detoxrodrigoalagunamorenodetox1997@outlook.es',
,'rodrigo@gmail.com'
,'detox@live.com'];

console.log(correos);
```

Comment: Nos muestras que has intentado por favor?, Considera leer [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Editado**

*Añadí la función para ordenar*

---

La función `filter` te puede servir para lo que buscas

De esta forma

```js
  var correos = ['al221511338@gmail.com', 'rodrigo@gmail.com', 'al221511338@gmail.com', 'detox@live.com', 'detoxrodrigoalagunamorenodetox1997@outlook.es', 'rodrigo@gmail.com', 'detox@live.com'];
  function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  }
  // función ordenar por dominio
  function orderByDomain(arr) {
    var obj = {
      gmail: [],
      hotmail: [],
      outlook: [],
      live: []
    };
    var domains = ['gmail.com', 'hotmail.com', 'outlook.com', 'outlook.es', 'live.com']; // listamos los dominios validos
    arr.forEach(function(val) {
      var _d = val.split('@')[1]; // obtenemos el dominio sin el '@'
      domains.forEach(function(d) {
        if (_d === d) {
          // comparamos para concatenar los valores en sus respectivos campos del objeto 'obj'
          obj[_d.split('.')[0]].push(val);
        }
      });
    });
    // por último eliminamos los elementos vacíos del objeto 'obj'
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
      if (obj[key].length === 0) delete obj[key];
    });
    return obj;
  }
  correos = orderByDomain(correos.filter(onlyUnique));
  console.log(correos.gmail)
```

Answer (score 3):

acá te hice una pequeña función que recorre un for en tu array, por cada iteracion de la misma va comparando el valor.

```
function getUnicoarray(array) {
  var unicoArray = [];

  // recorremos el array valores y keys
  for (var value of array) {
     // verificamos si el valor es distinto
    if (unicoArray.indexOf(value) === -1) {
      unicoArray.push(value);
    }
  }
  return unicoArray;
}

var correos = [
  "al221511338@gmail.com",
  "rodrigo@gmail.com",
  "al221511338@gmail.com",
  "detox@live.com",
  "detoxrodrigoalagunamorenodetox1997@outlook.es",
  "rodrigo@gmail.com",
  "detox@live.com"
];
var listaUnica = getUnicoarray(correos);
console.log(listaUnica);
```

Comment: muchas gracias era lo que necesitaba se lo agradezco